# What words can I use to indicate how hungry I am?

Tags: single-word-requests, idioms, synonyms

Besides "I'm hungry" and "I'm starving", where starving is more than hungry, are there other phrases to indicate how hungry you are (including slangs, if any)?

Comment: "I could eat a horse" is a common phrase, but I guess you're looking for single words.

Comment: @JoseK, please post this as an answer. I'll edit my question to clarify that it doesn't have to be a single word.

Comment: "I'm all rumbly in my tumbly" would work with those that watched/remember Pooh Bear, but even they might look at you strangely...Funny. I think this is the second time I've mentioned Pooh Bear on this site this week...

Comment: @F'x How is this not a single word request? Isn't consensus that _single word requests_ do not have be literally single words in order to be tagged as such?

Comment: @Billare: if Ivo's looking for many synonyms, I don't see how it could be single word. To mean, single-word-request is when you say “I remember there's a word that would express this concept, but it forgot it”. Not a big deal anyway, maybe we could take this discussion to meta?

Comment: Reading all these answers is making me hungry.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

My own favourite is ***[esurient](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/esurient)***. Other than that, *ravenous* and *famished* are both quite strong. *Malnourished*, *undernourished*, *underfed* indicate chronicity. *Empty* is used informally, as is *peckish* (which is British).

Comment: +1 for ravenous et al.  'esurient' is new to me, I'll test run it today.

Comment: **Esurient** is archaic and is rarely used; it kind of connotes greediness.

Answer (score 11):

[I could eat a horse](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/I+could+eat+a+horse) is a commonly used phrase.

I've just come across ["Hungry as a wolf"](http://www.omniglot.com/language/idioms/index.php) credited as Italian, Turkish and Cornish phrases to mean "very hungry" but I've not heard this in English before.

Comment: I take it you're not a child of the eighties then?

Comment: If Cornish is not a dialect of English, then what is it?

Comment: In Cornwall it only applies when used as: _'Hungry as a werewolf!_ ;)

Comment: @ghoppe: is that a Duran Duran reference

Comment: Matt Эллен, Cornish is a Celtic language. English is a Germanic language.

Comment: Also the extension to the phrase, "I could eat a scabby horse", should be mentioned.

Answer (score 7):

I guess this is more upper-class/formal, but you could say

> I'm **famished**; I could eat an entire elephant.

You could also say, though I'm not sure how "idiomatic" this is:

> **My stomach is growling**.

Comment: Hm, I just realized you usually only hear this word used this way, always in the past tense, always intransitive.

Comment: it's indeed quite dated as an infinitive: *[“the soldier growth into desperate terms, and spare not to say their officers, that they will run away and steal rather than famish”](http://dspace.wul.waseda.ac.jp/dspace/bitstream/2065/26864/1/019.pdf)*

Answer (score 6):

I sometimes say I'm **peckish** when I'm slightly hungry. It's not quite as strong as saying I'm famished or starving.

Comment: One of my colleagues has recently returned from a 6 month stay in Birmingham, and since then he is always *peckish*, never hungry :)

Answer (score 6):

I've got the [munchies](http://www.wordnik.com/words/munchies)!

Answer (score 3):

Another couple to throw into the fire are:

**Voracious**, or **covetous**, as in:

> A voracious, or covetous appetite

Or thinking in terms of slang that hasn't been mentioned, you could use **dog-hungry**.

These all really only count for the higher level of hunger, see: greed.

Answer (score 2):

As far as slang goes, I have heard *fungry*, to mean 'f****ing hungry'.  Of course, this is somewhat vulgar, so keep that in mind when using it.

Answer (score 1):

Many idioms exist in this area. As mentioned, *I could eat a horse*, but there are more:

- I could eat an ox
- I could eat an ox between two bread vans
- I could eat the north end of a south bound bear
- I could eat a scabby donkey/dog
- Hungry as a bear
- My belly thinks my throat's been cut

Comment: And which area would this happen to be? :)

Comment: I meant the area of hunger.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I thought you were referring to a physical location, seriously!

Answer (score 0):

For added emphasis, you also sometimes hear (in BritEng at least):

- Starving hungry
- Starving to death

More tongue in cheek:

- WANT FOOD NOW
- Desirous of imminent sustenance

Comment: In the US a common tongue-in-cheek one would be to double up and start moaning, or similar. "Desirous of imminent sustenance" amuses me. I'll have to use it and see what funny looks I get. :)

Comment: "Desirous of imminent sustenance" amuses me too, though I can't really recommend it. I don't *think* that I invented it, but a quick search didn't bring anything up.

Comment: And "immediate" would make more sense than "imminent", but it doesn't sound so good :)

Answer (score 0):

- *I am so hungry; I could swallow a horse*
- *I am so hungry; I could swallow a sheep*
- *I am so hungry; I could swallow a hippo*
- *I am so hungry; I could swallow a horse whole*
- *I am so hungry; I could swallow a **Big Mac*** :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm so hungry I could eat a scabby donkey between six bread vans is another one, my mum uses it all the time.

Answer (score -1):

I'm so hungry, I could eat a candy cane.

Comment: A whole candy cane!